# Getting bearer token in blob format how to get in a actual format in logical tree?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

How to configure oauth bearer token to http request node in esq in iib
while getting token in a blob format in logical tree

I tried to convert in character but it is throwing exception like unsupported charector format  in iib

Comment: Can you show your ESQL code, please?

Comment: Also, please quote the actual error - your description of the error does not sound accurate.